# vitis 2020.2 error debug

Tags: c, fpga, vivado

Я пробую отладить проект в vitis 2020.2, но данное sdk игнорирует точки останова при дебаг режиме.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал изменения параметры компиляции, в частности изменил уровень оптимизации на O0, т.к. предпалага, что компилятор просто выбрасывает некоторые строчки в процессе оптимизации.
[image: configuration bsp]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык или задайте его на enSO.

Comment: Скорее всего ваше приложение не включает код из этого файла.